# How to enable Changes tab Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

My Changes tab in Android Studio disappeared suddenly.

VCS button is also not available after upgrading it to Android Studio and Gradle 1.1.0.

I could right click on files and see "Local History" but not the changes with respect to latest from Repository.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Found it. View --> Tools Window --> Changes.

Also need to enable proper Version control under     VCS > Enable Version Control Integration

Comment: currently View --> Tool Windows --> Version Control

Comment: Note also that the Version Control button (and most all git functionality) will disappear if `git init` has not been run on the project. A warning message would have been nice in this case -- yes, looking at you JetBrains :-)

Answer (score 10):

Simply disable the following option under

> *File | Settings | Version Control | Commit:*

[image]